# Connecting to SQL Server using Netbeans 7.0 is hanging

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7, sqljdbc4 to connect to SQL Server 2k8 R2, but it is hanging with no response.

I tried to connect by code and create connection using Netbeans, but both are hanging with no response after a long wait time. What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to figure out on what stage it is 'hanging'
 - Can you see the connection come up on the server when running `sp_who2` in SSMS ?
 - If yes, use `DBCC INPUTBUFFER (<spid>)` to see what's going on (or profiler)
 - If not, are you sure you've got the connection-string correct ?
 - If not, does the server allow for remote connections (silly I know, but been there)
 - What error message do you get when you lower the connection-timeout to say 10 seconds ?